# how i'd apply proxy settings on simple tcp client in c++

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, proxy, client

I want ask question about c++ socket .

I have a tcp client , and proxy configure in my system(linux ubuntu) , and I want the tcp client use some proxy or the systems proxy , what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a general proxy. A proxy is usually protocol specific (e.g. http proxy, imap proxy etc). Then there is SOCKS which works for general TCP (and UDP with SOCKS5). And then there might be a way to tunnel generic TCP through a HTTP proxy with a CONNECT request, but this often allows only limited target ports.

So you better specify what kind of proxy you have in your network.

Comment: I had found a socks4\5 proxy , and apply him all over the system , my simple tcp client will get his settings ?

Comment: No, you have to speak the socks protocol. But there are tools which overwrite the usual connect function with a preloaded function, so that you can talk with the socks proxy without changing you program: http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/index.php

Comment: I have tryed to realize that ..
this is the pastebin code : http://pastebin.com/dGSZV0J8
I do this by following in wikipedia socks ..

Comment: @user3511820: not really. Socks4 requires you to send 9 bytes in case no authorization is required and then receive 8 from the server. What you do is something completely different.

Comment: I would rather prefer if you add before each read and write what you think you are doing in reference to the Socks4 protocol, e.g. how many bytes your read/write, what they should contain etc. Either you find out then yourself what you got wrong or I can better point out where you read the specification wrong.

Comment: I have tryed do this by this example :

A typical SOCKS4 connection request looks like this:

SOCKS Client to SOCKS Server:

    field 1: SOCKS version number, 1 byte, must be 0x04 for this version
    field 2: command code, 1 byte:
        0x01 = establish a TCP/IP stream connection
        0x02 = establish a TCP/IP port binding
    field 3: network byte order port number, 2 bytes
    field 4: network byte order IP address, 4 bytes
    field 5: the user ID string, variable length, terminated with a null (0x00)

Comment: The description is correct, but this is not what you've implemented.

Comment: Ok I have no idea for what did i wrong , I have write line by line, and size by size by this article , can you help me ? please just a comments . my english are so bad, and i harder to learn noramlly.

Comment: Like I said: please document for every send and recv what you put in and what you expect back and compare it to the socks4 protocol. Some hints: a byte should have length 1 and not 4 in send and there are lots of recv for no reason.